# JavaScript doesn't work in my PHP code

Tags: php

i have this in my **index.php**

```
include 'app/Core.php';     
echo Core::getPageHtml();
```

in **Core.php**

```
final class Core
{
    public static function getPageHtml()
{
    ob_start();
    include 'layout.php';
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    return $html;
}
}
```

**layout.php** is normal html code, i can see de page, just perfect, but the javascript code doesn't work, i even write an alert('hello world'), like this

```
   <script type="text/javscript">
     alert('hello world');
   </script>
```

so, it should be simple, but i can make it work, what am i missing here?
need some help with this code

Comment: are you sure `layout.php` is being included (maybe wrong path, or something..)? try replacing `include 'layout.php';` by `echo "<script>alert('x');</script>";` and see if it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"text/javscript"` -> `"text/javascript"`

Comment: Another alternative is to not enter the language at all. The W3C are the only people who would ever care.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, you had text/javascript spelled wrong though.